Function seemingly returns incorrect value
When calling the function as follows:
getSmallestStringLength(["", "h"]);

It returns 1. Shouldn't it return 0, as the first string is zero-length? What am I missing?


function getSmallestStringLength(strs) {
  let result;

  for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    if (!result) {
      result = strs[i].length;
    } else if (strs[i].length < result) {
      result = strs[i].length;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
console.log(
  getSmallestStringLength(["", "h"])
);




This should be easy to debug (stepping through the code, inspecting variables, ...). What is the if condition in the second iteration of the loop? Did you check?

When the first string is evaluated, result is set to your expected answer 0.
However, your !result test treats 0 the same way it would treat a variable that is undefined. It therefore returns the next non-zero string length.

Perhaps use the word and definition of "falsy" in your answer?

Thanks so much... It's so obvious once you mentioned it, I wonder how I could have missed it. Must have been the late hour....
